# reuse property values in upgrade versions

Tags: wix, wix3.6

Wix:  Is there a way to reuse previously installed version property values in upgrade version using Wix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will need to save them in the registry. This is called the the [Remember property pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern)